# What means the status of signal?

Tags: linux

I am reading book "Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment".

Here is the sentence that I can't understand:

*Specifically, the `exec()` functions change the  disposition of any signals being caught to their default action and leave the status of all other signals alone.*

I understand the action of signals are changed to default action. But, what is the status of signal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

> *Specifically, the exec() functions change the disposition of any signals being caught to their default action and leave the status of all other signals alone.*

the "status of all other signals" refers to the signals which are not being caught, e.g, they are being ignored (`SIG_IGN`).

If your program has added a handler for a signal, the program could catch that signal (except of course for `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` which cannot be caught).  When you call an `exec()` function, none of those signal handlers apply to the program after calling the `exec()` function.

If your program did not add a signal handler for a given signal, then calling an `exec()` function does not change the way that signal affects your program.

Signal handlers can be established with [`signal`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html) or [`sigaction`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html).

Comment: Then what means leave alone?? And catch means that we define the signal handler using `signal()`? Càn you explain more?

Comment: catching a signal means setting up a signal handler using signal()/sigaction(). "leave alone" means unchanged -> action for these is not changed.